# Fix import moviepy.editor

Tags: python, moviepy

Until 2 days ago, everything worked.

But today i have the following error:

```
C:\Users\Χρήστος\Desktop\Papinhio player\project\main>python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import moviepy.editor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioClip
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 7, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.io.ffmpeg_audiowriter import ffmpeg_audiowrite
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from moviepy.config import get_setting
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\config.py", line 36, in <module>
    FFMPEG_BINARY = get_exe()
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py", line 47, in get_exe
    import imageio_ffmpeg
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._utils import get_ffmpeg_exe, get_ffmpeg_version
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_filename
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall moviepy with pip (pip uninstall moviepy)
2. Upgrade python (python -m ensurepip --upgrade)
3. Download whl file from: https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/#files
4. cd in the unzip downloaded folder and then
5. python setup.py build
6. python setup.py install

And everything is ok now!!!